# How do I handle symbolics links in projects under source control?

Tags: php, zend-framework, shared-libraries, directory-structure, project-layout

We have several php projects.  The projects use the Zend Framework and we also maintain a common core library with various functions.

Right now my directory structure looks like this

```
project-1
        \application
                    \model
                    \views
                    \controllers
        \libraray
                 \Zend -> symlink to ../../libraries/Zend
                 \Core -> symlink to ../../libraries/Core
                 \Project1Lib
project-2
        \application
                    \model
                    \views
                    \controllers
        \libraray
                 \Zend -> symlink to ../../libraries/Zend
                 \Core -> symlink to ../../libraries/Core
                 \Project2Lib
libraries
         \Zend
         \Core
```

In Subversion I seem to be having trouble with the sym links, it's adding the actual files (I'm using Syncro on the Mac) instead of just the sym links.  But it got me thinking and I was wondering what the best way of laying out the project is in order to avoid having multiple copies of the same libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official subversion client can deal with [symlinks](http://help.collab.net/index.jsp?topic=/faq/symlinks.html), but obviously your client doesn't handle them properly.